# Prevent recursion in a Laravel Eloquent's self relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, recurrence

Consider a table of nested locations which has columns for the `location_id`, its `name` and a `parent_id`. This parent field lets you know that you're in a nested location.

Example setup:

```
Locations
-----------------------------------
location_id |   name   | parent_id
-----------------------------------
      1     |   Isle A  |   NULL
      2     | Column 23 |    1
      3     |  Shelf 2  |    2
      4     |   Box C   |    3
```

Let's say we have an item sitting in `location_id=4`.
We now want to easily show the item's full location in a comma separated format. We expect to see:

> Isle A, Column 23, Shelf 2, Box C

In order to achieve that, I have the following Laravel Model with a `full_name()` function which takes care of formatting and recursive calls:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Location extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'locations';
    protected $primaryKey = 'location_id';

    protected $with = [
        'location'
    ];

    public function location()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Location', 'parent_id', 'location_id');
    }

    public function full_name()
    {
        return ($this->location ? $this->location->full_name() . ', ' : '') . $this->name;
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy soo far, works correctly and outputs what I need it to.
Now imagine down the line, some other piece of code allows for a mistake and the following happens:

```
Locations
-----------------------------------
location_id |   name   | parent_id
-----------------------------------
      1     |   Isle A  |   NULL
      2     | Column 23 |    3
      3     |  Shelf 2  |    2
      4     |   Box C   |    3
```

Notice that location #2's `parent_id` changed to `3`. This creates an infinite loop of joins between 2 and 3. Laravel will not detect this recurrence (after all we're telling it to keep joining) and the execution will eventually die. **This is my problem**.

A possible solution I thought about would be to keep an ongoing list of "visited" location_id's, and if we stumble upon a repeat, we terminate the execution. If this was a "normal" function, I recon something like this would work:

```php
public function location($recurrence_guard = [])
{
    if(in_array($this->location_id, $recurrence_guard)) {
        return collect([]); // or null?
    }
    array_push($recurrence_guard, $this->location_id);

    return $this->hasOne('\App\Location(<somehow pass $recurrence_guard_in_here>)', 'location_id', 'parent_id');
}
```

Clearly this is nonsense and that's not how Laravel's relationships work. I'm looking for ideas on how to pass extra parameters into the relationships or for any better ideas on how to design this.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see any real life situation where a a child model could be the parent model of it's own parent model. I think your issue is most probably related to your database design.

Comment: @RobertKujawa You're right in that I can't see any situation where this would be a case. However, mistakes happen (both by users and myself as the coder down the line in the project), so I want to future proof this model and make sure that i can never loop itself, even if the data in the DB is incorrect.

Comment: In that case try validating the request data, if someone tries to update the `parent_id` make sure that the `parent_model->parent_id != current_model->id`. That way you will never have a situation like this.

Comment: This won't work if the recursion happens more than 1 relation away. Additionally, I'm looking for a solution that will protect code that relies on potentially already "broken" data. I know I will have to make every effort to make sure this can't happen in the DB in the first place. But if it does, I don't want to bring the house down, so to speak.